# Terraform: "known only after apply" ISSUE

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm creating an `aws_subnet` and referencing it in another resource.

Example:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "mango" {
     vpc_id     = aws_vpc.mango.id
     cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidr}"
  }
```

The reference

```
 network_configuration {
    subnets          = "${aws_subnet.mango.id}"
  }
```

When planning it I get
`aws_subnet.mango.id is a string, known only after apply`
error. I'm new to Terraform. Is there something similar to Cloudformation's `DependsOn` or `Export/Import`?

Comment: The message you've quoted here is not an error message itself, but rather some diagnostic information included as part of an error message. I think you'll get a better answer if you share the entire error message, which will start with `Error: ` and then possibly include a source code snippet and diagnostic information followed by one or more paragraphs of explanation text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a case of [explicit dependency](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies#manage-explicit-dependencies).
The argument `depends_on` similar to CloudFormation's `DependsOn` solves such dependencies.

Note: *"Since Terraform will wait to create the dependent resource until after the specified resource is created, adding explicit dependencies can increase the length of time it takes for Terraform to create your infrastructure."*

Example:

```
depends_on = [aws_subnet.mango]
```

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
 cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidr}"
```

should look like

```
 cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr
```

And this line:

```
subnets          = "${aws_subnet.mango.id}"
```

should look like

```
subnets          = aws_subnet.mango.id
```

Terraform gives a warning when a string value only has a template in it. The reason is that for cases like yours, it's able to make a graph with the bare value and resolve it on apply, but it's unable to make the string without creating the resource first.

Answer (score 2):

The information like `ID` or other such information which will be generated by AWS, cannot be predicted by `terraform plan` as this step only does a dry run and doesn't apply any changes.

The fields which have `known only after apply` is not an error, but just informs the user that these fields only get populated in terraform state after its applied. The dependency order is handled by Terraform and hence referring values (even those which have `known only after apply`) will be resolved at run time.

Comment: Thanks. I can really use a solution if you have one.

Comment: Informative, but not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The error in this case is not the string "known only after apply" but the message "Incorrect attribute value type".

`subnets` (plural) requires a *list* of strings but you gave only one string.

```
network_configuration {
  subnets          = ["${aws_subnet.mango.id}"]
}
```

The `depends_on` is not necessary in this case, tf resolves this dependency by itself. `depends_on` is only important if tf can't get this by itself.

writing `"${foo.bar}"` instead of `foo.bar` is also no problem but doesn't follow tf's code-style-rules.